# MYSQL Where on DateTime wrong results

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

I have a MySQL query to select some rows according to a datetime field.

The date time field is created_at and it also has a BTREE index.
When I write a statement with where on the date time I keep receiving wrong results for some reason.

Example Query:

```
Select text,UNIX_TIMESTAMP(created_at),DATE(created_at) 
       from Services where Binary text like '%Rd' or Binary text like '%Rd%'
       and DATE(created_at)>=STR_TO_DATE('2014-03-07','%Y-%m-%d') 
       order by UNIX_TIMESTAMP(created_at);
```

The result is:
'2014-02-21'
'2014-02-26'
'2014-02-27'
'2014-03-03'
'2014-03-05'
'2014-03-06'

And the rest are correct. What happens with these rows? May this is a problem of the BTREE index? For every date I always get 5-10 rows of previous days.

It cant a time zone problem since I am receiving rows from previous dates.

The result is the same when:

```
Select text,UNIX_TIMESTAMP(created_at),DATE(created_at),MONTH(created_at) 
from Services where Binary text like '%Rd' or Binary text like '%Rd%'
 and YEAR(created_at)>=2014 and MONTH(created_at)=3 and DAY(created_at)>=7
 order by UNIX_TIMESTAMP(created_at);
```

Edit: Found I have forgotten an OR

Comment: Try using `%m` for month instead of `%c`

Comment: Hey @nikosdi, you shouldn't add `[solved]` to the title, it is not part of your question. Neither is the result / solution part of it. You could add it as a self-answer, for instance? Marking an answer as the correct one is the way to show it was solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several interesting things going on in your query.

One: `AND` and `OR` clauses are right-associative.  What you have is actually this, which pulls in some rows that don't match your date comparison.

```
 Binary text like '%Rd' OR ( 
          Binary text like '%Rd%' 
     and DATE(created_at)>=STR_TO_DATE('2014-03-07','%Y-%m-%d'
     )
```

What you want is

```
         ( Binary text like '%Rd' OR  Binary text like '%Rd%' ) 
     and DATE(created_at)>=STR_TO_DATE('2014-03-07','%Y-%m-%d'
```

But actually all you need is

```
         Binary text like '%Rd%' 
     and DATE(created_at)>=STR_TO_DATE('2014-03-07','%Y-%m-%d'
```

Because everything that matches your first `like` clause also matches the second.

Two: You are systematically defeating the use of your BTREE index on `created_at`. Use this instead, to permit the index to be used.

```
  WHERE created_at >= STR_TO_DATE('2014-03-07','%Y-%m-%d')
```

Third, you are making extra work for the server with your `ORDER BY` clause.  `DATETIME` data types order themselves just as well as `TIMESTAMP` types. So use:

```
 order by created_at
```

Given all those observations, you should consider using this for your query.

```
Select text,UNIX_TIMESTAMP(created_at),DATE(created_at) 
 from Services 
where Binary text like '%Rd%'
  and created_at >= STR_TO_DATE('2014-03-07','%Y-%m-%d') 
order by created_at;
```